# I am try to insert data into oracle from a pandas dataframe and this error is coming '''Python value of type numpy.int64 not supported.'''

Tags: python, oracle, pipeline, cx-oracle

This is my code

```py
imp = df[['ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION_ID','ID_ACC_TRAN']]
impt = [tuple(x) for x in imp.values]
impt
imptext = 'INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION_DATA_TEMP(ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION_ID,ID_ACC_TRAN) values (: 1,: 2)'
cur.executemany(imptext,[x for x in impt])
connect.commit()
```

But i am get an error like

```
NotSupportedError: Python value of type numpy.int64 not supported.
```

I tried converting the data type to normal python int that does'nt work to .can anyone help me on this

Any answer and help for the question is appreciated

Comment: "I tried converting the data type to normal python int that doesn't work to." Can you share this code ?

Comment: The first Google search hit leads to the solution.  See https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/430